# Read Video from INTERNAL storage

Tags: android, internal-storage

This is the code to save my video to the internal storage(maybe I'm saving it wrong):

```
private String saveVideo() {
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.back_lungs);

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/videoDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("videoDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create videoDir
    File mypath = new File(directory, "video1.mp4");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        mypath.setReadable(true,false);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        int read = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) == -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Now Im getting the video from he raw folder, but i will later download it from the internet(this is not the problem).

And this is the code to read the video but it fails:

```
private void loadVideoFromStorage(String path) {


        File f = new File(path, "video1.mp4");

        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.fromFile(f));
        videoView.start();


}
```

Comment: "This is the code to save my video to the internal storage" -- I recommend getting rid of the `ContextWrapper` (useless), plus calling `fos.flush()` and `fos.getFD().sync()` before `fos.close()` (ensures bytes are written to disk before continuing). IIRC, the video player has no access to your internal storage. You might try temporarily writing this to external storage (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`) and see if that helps. If it does, I am not sure how to fix it with `VideoView`; with `MediaPlayer`, I think `setDataSource(FileDescriptor)` works.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have just one question, i should write it temporarily to external storage just before i want to read it?

Comment: Yes. More specifically, I mean change your `File directory` to point to a location on external storage (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`), to run a test and see if you can play the video from there.

Comment: Thanks it will save me some time.